# showing a functional on $l^p$ is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

let $l^p$ be a [sequence space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#%E2%84%93p_spaces) and $a: l^p \to \mathbb C$ be a [linear functional](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearFunctional.html) defined by $x \mapsto \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j x_j$. How do I show $a$ is a [bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator)? I want to show that  there exists a fixed real constant $M>0$ s.t. for all $x\in l^p$ with $\|x\|_p = 1$, $|\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j x_j| < M$.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + Please [avoid "no-clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). Edit your post to include the definition of "(the linear functional) $a$ is bounded", your attempt(s) to prove it, and the point where you are stuck.

Comment: Are there any additional assumptions on $a$?

Comment: @nowhere nope, check the answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4189010/exercise-7-page-93-functional-analysis-book-of-conway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is understood that the series $\sum a_ix_i$ converges to a  complex number for every $x \in \ell^{p}$.
Define $T_n(x)= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_kx_k$. Check that $T_N$ is a bounded linear functional with norm $(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}|a_k|^{q})^{1/q}$ where $\frac  1p+\frac  1q=1$. Now apply Uniform boundeness principle to conclude that $\sum |a_n|^{q} <\infty$ and use Holder's inequality to  finish the proof.

EDIT: As suggested by Anne Bauval we can just use the fact that pointiise limit of  sequence of bounded operators between  Banach spaces is bounded: Another simple consequence of Uniform boundeness principle.

Comment: Misprint: $T_N$ should be $T_n.$ (twice)

Comment: This argument was already in [the answer to the post which the OP was wondering about](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4189569/386889). But I don't think we need to talk about $q$-norms and Hölder. Applying the uniform boundedness principle to $(T_n)$ directly gives the desired $M.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you. I have incorporated your suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

No advanced theorems are needed.

Let $1<p\le  \infty$
We are going to show that $\{a_n\}\in \ell^q,$ where $q$ is the dual exponent. Once it is done,  the Hôlder inequality implies $\|T\|\le \|\{a_n\}\|_q.$

Assume by contradiction that $\sum |a_n|^q=\infty.$ Then there is an increasing sequence $n_k$ of positive integers so that $\sum_{j=n_{k-1}+1}^{n_k}|a_j|^q\ge 1.$ Let $$x_n={\overline{a_n}|a_n|^{q-2}\over \left(\sum_{j=n_{k-1}+1}^{n_k}|a_j|^q\right)^{1/p}}{1\over k}, \quad n_{k-1}<n\le n_k $$ following the convention $x_n=0$ if $a_n=0.$ Then $$\sum|x_n|^p=\sum {1\over k^p}<\infty$$ and $$\sum a_nx_n\ge \sum {1\over k}=\infty$$ Thus we have obtained a contradiction.

For $p=1$ we will show that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded, hence $\|T\|\le \|\{a_n\}\|_\infty.$ Assume by contradiction $|\{a_n\}\|_\infty=\infty.$ There is an increasing sequence $n_k$ so that $|a_{n_k}|\ge { k}.$ Let $x_n=\overline{a_n}|a_n|^{-1}{1\over k^2}$ for $n=n_k$ and $a_n=0$ for remaining values of $n.$ Then $\|\{x_n\}\|_1=\sum {1\over k^2}<\infty$ and $\sum a_nx_n\ge \sum {1\over k}=\infty.$

The same argument for $p=2$ has been applied  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4697253/inner-product-on-sequence-space-l2/4697393#4697393).